# How to restrict edit/delete funtion for all except the document owner

Tags: permissions, office-365

Update to my below question. Thank you for your comments. My scenario is I have a library on my site collection that I need to edit the user access to. I want a particular group to be able to upload to the library and edit the documents they upload but only those. Same request as in the below link but I am on O365 and this capability is OOTB for lists just not for Libraries. Thanks

My questions relates to a prior post. I am trying to create the same edit/delete restriction as in the link below. My question is where do I place the code? Do I use the Script editor web part? I just need to know where to enter this so I can use it. Your assistance is appreciated.

[How to restrict user from deleting\editing documents if user is not author of that document](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147875/how-to-restrict-user-from-deleting-editing-documents-if-user-is-not-author-of-th)

Comment: I think you need to create a Remote Event Receiver(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Answer in your link uses server-side object model and event receivers. Those features are not available in Office 365.

If you want to do that in code, you need to use remote event receiver. Unfortunately this isn't going to be a trivial task. You'll have to convert the code to Client Side Object Model, create remote hosted app and host it in the place that can be reached by Office 365.

If you provide more details about your scenario, maybe someone will be able to suggest different approach.